# syslog spammed with authdaemond: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/user is already mounted

Tags: syslog, ecryptfs

I setup my new server with harddisk-encryption and now I noticed that /var/log/syslog is full of the following lines:

`server authdaemond: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/user is already mounted`

Should I be worried? How can I fix this / get rid of it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please flag your question and ask to have it moved to a different site if you feel that it is better suited on a different StackExchange site, instead of reposting the same question.

Comment: Sorry - I didnt know this is possible. Can you please guide me what to do? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, you just click "flag" under your question, select "This question is in need of a moderator's attention", and in the text box that appears specify where you think the question would be better off. Don't worry about doing that now, but you can probably go ahead and flag your old AskUbuntu question as a duplicate to get it closed.

Comment: Thanks - I will use this the next time. For now I deleted the original post at askubuntu.

Comment: eCryptfs is for home or other folder encryption, related to but different from whole-disk encryption (uses LUKS usually). When are these messages appearing, every time a user logs in? Is their home being "closed" or unmounted successfully when they log out?

Comment: Xen2050 - I dont know exactly when the message is triggered - but it could be related to my postfix installation which is accessing the home-folder for Maildir

Comment: I'm noticing the same issue in my logs. Wondering what this is about. Wish someone could provide some insight for what this means.